# How to ajax POST json data along with files?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios, multipartform-data

I'm currently changing a form in a React project to allow uploading of files along with the form. Currently the ajax post looks something like the following:

```
return axios.post(url, {
      item: {
        prop: 'test',
        otherProp: 'test2'
        arrayOfObjects: [
          {
            prop: 'test'
          },
          {
            prop: 'test'
          },
        ]
      }
    });
```

Now the problem is I need to send multiple pictures to be uploaded along with the other form data.

Everything I've seen says to use `FormData`, but the problem is I have lots of nested arrays and object literals, which makes using `FormData` rather complex.

Is there anyway I can submit multiple files along with my JSON data without increasing the complexity a ton?

I'm also using a rails backend if there's anything I can do on that end to make things easier.

Comment: FormData is the way to do it, perhaps you need to look at your data structures as it sounds like the issue is there really?

Comment: I made a recursive method to convert my json object into a FormData Object, I think this is my best solution. I've updated my original post to show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by creating a method to convert json data to a `FormData` object.

```
function convertToFormData(data) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  convertToFormDataRecursive(fd, '', data);
  return fd;
}

function convertToFormDataRecursive(formData, key, data) {
  if (moment.isMoment(data)) {
    convertToFormData(formData, key, data.toString());
  }
  else if (data instanceof File) {
    formData.append(key, data, data.name);
  }
  else if (data instanceof Array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      convertToFormDataRecursive(formData, key + '[' + i + ']', data[i]);
    }
  }
  else if (data instanceof Object) {
    for (let prop in data ) {
      var newKey = (key != '') ? key + '[' + prop + ']' : prop;
      convertToFormDataRecursive(formData, newKey, data[prop]);
    }
  }
  else {
    formData.append(key, data);
  }
}
```